# Unable to print multiindex dataframe to excel with merged cells

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df` which looks as following:

```
Date        ConstraintType  Col1    Col2
2020-07-15  N-S             w1      521133
2020-07-15  N-S             w2      550260
2020-07-15  CSD             d1      522417
2020-07-15  CSD             d2      534542
2020-07-15  A               d4      534905
2020-07-15  B               d5      534904
```

The index of dataframe is:

```
df.index
Out[6]: 
MultiIndex([('2020-07-15',  'N-S'),
            ('2020-07-15',  'N-S'),
            ('2020-07-15',  'CSD'),
            ('2020-07-15',  'CSD'),
            ('2020-07-15', 'A'),
            ('2020-07-15', 'B')],
           names=['Date', 'ConstraintType'])
```

But when I print it to excel it appears as following:

[image]

I was expecting the following:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\ram\Desktop\z1.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the provided DataFrame:

1. Use `.reset_index()` to remove the index columns from the index
2. Use `where`, and `.shift` to make all of the cell values blank except for the first occurrence of those values in the columns `Date` and `ConstraintType`.
3. Finally, use `.set_index` to put them back on the index, this time with only one unrepeated value and write `to_excel`. *Now*, `merge_cells=True` *should work*.

code:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['Date'] = df['Date'].where(df['Date'] != df['Date'].shift(), '')
df['ConstraintType'] = df['ConstraintType'].where(df['ConstraintType'] != df['ConstraintType'].shift(), '')
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'ConstraintType'])
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\ram\Desktop\z1.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

excel output:

[image]

Comment: Why this step: ."set_index(['Date', 'ConstraintType']).reset_index()"

Comment: @Zanam I put as a comment to the right of that `#if you already have a multi-index set up then do df=df.reset_index()` It sounds like you have a multi-index already set up, so I will adjust the answer. `.reset_index()` gets the columns out of a multi-index and as normal columns, so that you can manipulate the data before later using `.set_index()` to put them back as a multi-index.

Comment: I meant why did you set index only to reset it again or was that a bug in original code?

Comment: i used `pd.read_clipboard()` to read in your data so in order to create a multi index dataframe, for testing, I had to use `set_index(['Date', 'ConstraintType'])` @Zanam , which is why I made the comment that you can just do `df=df.reset_index()` if you already had a multi-index set up.

Answer (score 2):

In pandas the inner most index must label each row.
Therefore the inner most index must be manually handled, as shown in @David Erickson 's answer. Pandas automatically hides outer indices; see below example:

```
import pandas as pd

tuples = [["2020-07-15", "N-S"],
          ["2020-07-15", "N-S"],
          ["2020-07-15", "CSD"],
          ["2020-07-15", "CSD"],
          ["2020-07-15", "A"],
          ["2020-07-15", "B"]
         ]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Date', 'ConstraintType'])

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["w1", 521133],
    ["w2", 550260],
    ["d1", 522417],
    ["d2", 534542],
    ["d4", 534905],
    ["d5", 534904],
], columns=["Col1", "Col2"],
   index=index
)

print(df, '\n'*2)
print(df.swaplevel(0,1))
```

Returns:

```
                          Col1    Col2
Date       ConstraintType             
2020-07-15 N-S              w1  521133
           N-S              w2  550260
           CSD              d1  522417
           CSD              d2  534542
           A                d4  534905
           B                d5  534904


                          Col1    Col2
ConstraintType Date                   
N-S            2020-07-15   w1  521133
               2020-07-15   w2  550260
CSD            2020-07-15   d1  522417
               2020-07-15   d2  534542
A              2020-07-15   d4  534905
B              2020-07-15   d5  534904
```

Reset index, clean former multi-index columns, then save to Excel without the need of setting the merge_cells option:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
row_filt = df['ConstraintType'].eq(df['ConstraintType'].shift())
df.loc[row_filt, 'ConstraintType'] = ''
row_filt = df['Date'].eq(df['Date'].shift())
df.loc[row_filt, 'Date'] = ''

df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\ram\Desktop\z1.xlsx')
```

Produces the following Excel:

[image]